# Groovy enum constructor matching

Tags: groovy, enums, constructor

I have the following Groovy enum:

```
enum Flower {
    Tulip(1),
    Daisy(2)

    private int rank

    Flower(int rank) {
        super()
        this.rank = rank
    }

    int getRank() {
        rank
    }
}
```

I also have a `GardernGenerator` class that takes a `Flower` instance as one of its constructor parameters:

```
class GardenGenerator {
  Flower flower
  int length
  int width
  boolean isOrganic

  GardenGenerator(Flower flower, int length, int width, boolean isOrganic) {
    super()

    this.flower = flower
    this.length = length
    this.width = width
    this.isOrganic =isOrganic
  }

  Garden createGarden() {
    // ...blah whatever
  }
}
```

When I try to create this `GardenGenerator` instance like so:

```
GardenGenerator gg = new GardenGenerator(Flower.Daisy, 5, 10, true)
```

I get constructor-related issues **on the `Flower` enum**:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: com.me.myapp.Flower(java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer)
```

**What do I need to do to `Flower` to fix this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Flower` enum should be implemented as follows:

```
enum Flower {
    Tulip(1),
    Daisy(2)

    private int rank

    Flower(int rank) {
        this.rank = rank
    }

    int getRank() {
        rank
    }
}
```

There's no need for `super()` call in enum's constructor.